# Phi doesn't display with \mathcal

Tags: math-mode, formatting, mathcal

With the following Codesnippet:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    $ L = \{ \underline{a} + \underline{b} \geq 0 \} $
    
    $x_{1} = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$
    
    $x_{2} = \{ \underline{a} \}$

\end{center}

\begin{align*}
    \mathcal {\phi} & = \ \{ \underline{a} + \underline{b}\}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

I receive the following error message:
[image]

And 9 listed problems all similar to:
Error Message 1: Missing } inserted.  } \end{align*}
Error Message 2: Extra }, or forgotten $.  \egroup

The only way by removing the errors is by deleting the $ next to \phi, but then  the Symbol I get is not phi anymore.

EDIT: I included the relevant parts of the file, to reproduce the error

If I remove the $, the symbol I receive is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What are you trying to achieve? If you remove the `$` around `\phi`, you should indeed get a phi, although probably not in a calligraphic font. To clarify your question, you should also complete your code snippet to make it directly compilable (while keeping it minimal), so that others can test it.

Comment: Does `\phi & = \{ \underline{a} + \underline{b}\}` produce your desired result?

Comment: @Vincent
I just included more code for compiling reasons.

Comment: And what do you expect `\mathcal{\phi}` to produce?

Comment: Removing \mathcal solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Without the package `isomath`, `$\phi$` and `$\mathcal{\phi}$` look the same.  There's still the question of what you were expecting to happen with `$\mathcal{\phi}$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

`\mathcal{\phi}` is wrong. Don't do it.

### Longer answer

The reported code produces no error during the LaTeX run.

On the other hand, it has several mistakes.

1. Using `center` to display equations/formulas is wrong; use `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` or `gather*` if more equations are grouped.
2. Using `align*` for a single equation is wrong either.
3. Adding more space to the right of the equals sign makes for a very unbalanced equation.
4. `\mathcal{\phi}` makes no sense, sorry.

The last point deserves some more comments.

The command `\mathcal` can be used with capital Latin letters and is guaranteed to produce some version of the corresponding calligraphic letter. I know of no font package that fails to produce calligraphic *capital Latin* letters with `\mathcal`; maybe some are nicer than others, but this is a matter of personal taste.

Under the standard setup and with the majority of font packages that deal with math fonts, `\mathcal{\phi}` would simply produce `\phi`, but it's wrong nonetheless. Why are you getting some random symbol?

Answer: `isomath`. Right or wrong, this package changes the mathcode of `\phi` from the standard `"011E` to `"711E`, which makes it respect the current math group; this is done in order to switch between upright and italic versions. However, it has the consequence that when `\phi` is used as the argument to `\mathcal`, TeX will typeset the character in position `"1E` of the font ***in the calligraphic*** math group, which in this case is the standard symbol font. With other font packages you might get different “random” symbols; for instance `stix2` would produce

[image]

With the standard fonts, the “random symbol” is

[image]